# file handling on web application

Tags: asp.net, session, authentication, fileserver

in my application file upload and download operations occur so many times. This situation causes some performance problems.

I tried so many things to improve the performance. But especially file uploading -big files- occurs so many times that i cannot do anything.

Now i thought that, i will use another server for file handling. And for other operations i m going to use different server.

But the things i m thinking about it

1- first of all is it a good idea

2- if it is, what about authentication and session ( since there will be two different application)

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far? Have you enabled static/dynamic gzip compression? Enabled browser caching?

Comment: @MikeSheehan i think it is not that important since there is so many (really many) file uploading. if you are still asking yes i enabled static compression. but i know these are for increasing the download opeartion performance. Am i right?